# Flutter dropdown button text overflow

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter

How can i make the text expand to it's content? I Tried this

```
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                items: _currentCitySelected.area
                                    .map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: dropDownStringItem,
                                    child: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                      dropDownStringItem,
                                      maxLines: 2,
//                                      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                    )),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    this._currentAreaSelected =
                                        newValueSelected;
                                  });
                                },
                                value: _currentAreaSelected,
                              ))
```

[[image] 
Text expands to content in drop down dialog content, but it does'nt works the same way in the main view.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `isExpanded` property of `DropdownButton` to `true`

```
isExpanded: true
```

Like that:

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              items: [...]
```

Comment: This does fix the wrap issue but causes another. Now, the DropdownButton takes the entire screen width. Is there any way to now shrink it? EDIT: Just needed to wrap the button in a Container with `constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300)`